# How to retrieve customFields on standard objects using Ant Migration Tool

Tags: migration-tool, ant

### Background

I'm trying to reset a dev org by using [this ant script](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/24618/636).

Most part of the customisations added by default are removed. However, I'm not being able to retrieve custom fields on Opportunity, Account and other standard objects.

I'm using this to get customfields :

```
<types><members>*</members><name>CustomField</name></types>
```

And this to get standard objects:

```
<types><members>*</members><name>CustomObject</name></types>
```

I've also tried:

```
<types><members>Account.*</members><name>CustomField</name></types>
```

and

```
<types><members>Opportunity</members><name>CustomObject</name></types>
```

Unsuccessfully

### Question

How can I retrieve custom fields on standard object on ant migration tool?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per the documentation the [CustomField](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_meta/Content/meta_types_list.htm) metadata type does not support wildcards sadly. You can access **Custom Fields** on **Standard Objects** by using the **CustomObject** metadata type as described [here](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_meta/Content/manifest_samples.htm#manifest_standard_objects) against specific Standard Objects. Then parse the .object file to build your **destructiveChanges.xml** file. Finally you can also use the [sf:listMetadata](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/daas/Content/forcemigrationtool_listmetadata.htm) task to download a list of all custom fields and then filter locally for Standard objects.

```
     <sf:listMetadata 
        username="${sf.username}"
        password="${sf.password}"
        metadataType="CustomField"/>
```

You might also be interested in an open-source **undeploy** Ant target published [here](https://github.com/financialforcedev/df12-deployment-tools#using-the-build-file-targets), that wraps most of what i suspect your trying to develop up into a single Ant target. Sadly Salesforce do not yet give us a 'clean my org' task, so we build our own!

Answer (score 5):

Fully naming the fields works e.g.:

```
<types>
    <members>Account.PayeeNameOverride1__c</members>
    <members>Account.PayeeNameOverride2__c</members>
    <members>Contact.JobDescriptionDate__c</members>
    <members>Contact.JobDescription__c</members>
    <name>CustomField</name>
</types>
```

Comment: Is there any way to make this more "generic" ?

Comment: We have no examples with wildcards...

Comment: But, how do you retrieve the customfields if you don't know the names?

Comment: Sorry I didn't pick up the "reset a dev org" part of your question so I see where you are coming from now. You could write Java code that uses the meta-data API to find the field names and then wrap that in an Ant task that is called first and edits your package.xml. But just manually tracking the field names is simpler unless you are talking about hundreds of fields.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to extract all the custom field of say Accout object , then write atleast one custom field name of account object and then write * in the other member tag like this

```
<types>
        <members>*</members>
        <members>Contact.Level__c</members>
        <name>CustomField</name>
    </types>
```

This will extract all the custom field of account object.

And if you want to extract custom as well as standard field then go for this

```
<types>
        <members>Contact</members>
        <name>CustomObject</name>
    </types>
```

Hope it helps

Comment: I tried the first snippet, and only the specified field migrated.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to extract particular fields.Then use this

```
<types>
<members>Case.EngineeringReqNumber__c</members>
<name>CustomField</name>
</types>
<types>
<members>Account</members>
```

Using the Force.com Migration Tool Constructing a Project Manifest

```
<name>CustomObject</name>
</types>
```